# Eclipse 2018-09 goes into endless build loop with Java 11 plugin: ClosedFileSystemException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-11, eclipse-2018-09

I'm running Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) on Windows 10. I'm using Open JDK 11 GA. I have a project using Java 8 compliant source code that compiles fine using the JDK, both from Eclipse and from Maven.

I want to use new Java 11 features, so first I changed the compiler source/target from Java 8 to Java 11. It still built find using Maven on the command line, but couldn't compile in Eclipse (see [Eclipse 2018-09 won't compile Java 11 source; thinks it is below 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52539867/421049)).

So I added the "Java 11 Support for Eclipse 2018-09" plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace. I restarted Eclipse and used `Alt+F5` to refresh my Maven projects. Eclipse then attempted to rebuild the project.

Now Eclipse goes into an endless loop, jumping between 8X% finished to 9X% finished, with repeated, endless errors such as these:

```
!SESSION 2018-09-27 08:08:51.188 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file …\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2018-09-27 08:11:22.981

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2018-09-27 08:11:22.981
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.nio.file.ClosedFileSystemException
  at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.ensureOpen(ZipFileSystem.java:1105)
  at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.checkAccess(ZipFileSystem.java:332)
  at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.checkAccess(ZipPath.java:830)
  at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:185)
  at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.exists(Files.java:2439)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathMultiReleaseJar.findClass(ClasspathMultiReleaseJar.java:206)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathLocation.findClass(ClasspathLocation.java:58)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.findClass(NameEnvironment.java:524)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.findType(NameEnvironment.java:556)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.fromSplitPackageOrOracle(LookupEnvironment.java:414)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.lambda$1(LookupEnvironment.java:289)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForTypeFromModules(LookupEnvironment.java:384)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:288)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:262)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:530)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.checkAndSetImports(CompilationUnitScope.java:254)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:501)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:868)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:394)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:386)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:318)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:265)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:185)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:798)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:219)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:262)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:315)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:318)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:370)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:391)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:145)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

There's no way to stop it. At least Eclipse doesn't freeze, so I hit the "close" button on the application title bar and manage to exit the program. I can get back into the program, but when I try to build it goes into the same endless loop.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539536) Eclipse bug

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449. I've added a link to this question to that ticket. Wow, my brand new Eclipse is broken now.

Comment: [_"Can you confirm that you have any multi version JAR files in your workspace/projects?"_](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539536#c6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Bug 539536](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539536), this issue has been fixed in the latest build of the Java 11 support patch. The problem was caused by a migration from *ZipFile* to the *java.nio* classes, the changes have been reverted for now but is still being discussed at the time of writing.

To install the fix, use the following update site in Eclipse and select *v20181001-0921* or more recent:
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.9-P-builds/P20181001-0525/